# regd setsocketopt and socket memory usage in TCP server

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I have a server socket which listens on clients. This server run in an infinite loop.
After each connected client is processed, the "connected socket" is closed. Should I use the setsocketopt on the file descriptor of the connected socket for reusability? As the server socket file descriptor is never closed, I want that socket to exist all the time.

Also, I am assuming that a listening server socket is blocked until a new client establishes connection, therefore this is not using up memory.Isn't it? Please help.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about `SO_REUSEADDR`, it doesn't let you re-use same socket for new connection. Also, I don't think this is going to buy you much. Creating new `fd/socket` isn't much of a task. You would find other bottlenecks than this.

But you can optimize, by not closing the connection (at server as well as client) so that **same client** can communicate over that connection for next requests. This will reduce your connection setup time.

Yes, by default listening socket is blocking so the `accept` call will be blocking. Also, this wouldn't be using much memory. You can make it non-blocking and use `poll` or `select` to determine new incoming connection.

Comment: so SO_REUSEADDR doesnt make sense for the connected socket file descriptor?

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to know what SO_REUSEADDR is for. It doesn't have the magical properties you are attributing to it. The socket will exist until you close it. SO_REUSEADDR isn't required for any socket descriptor in most circumstances. If you're not getting bind errors you don't need it at all.